# How to launch an application on a specific desktop from command line?

Tags: command-line

The title says it all. I usually have a console window on my Desktop 1; I would like to be able to launch from there any application specifying on which Desktop the application window should appear. For example, from my console window on Desktop 1. I would like to launch `thunderbird` in such a way that its window opens on Desktop 2. Is this possible? (I'm running kubuntu 9.04)

Comment: Do you mean you have two monitors and want to launch to the second one, or you have two workspaces(virtual desktops) and would like to launch to the other one?

Comment: I have a single monitor, and I would like to launch on any of my four workspaces (virtual desktops)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a few options.

## [Devil's Pie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)

[Here's an old tutorial](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/25/how-to-set-default-workspace-size-and-window-effects-in-gnome/).

## [wmctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/wmctrl.1.html)

You can make a script to move to the desired workspace and then launch your app ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1075301.html)):

```
#!/bin/bash
wmctrl -s 1
firefox --new-tab $@ &
```

Or you could launch your app and then move it. I think something like this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
thunderbird &
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -t 1
# if thunderbird takes a while to launch, you may need to find the window yourself:
#wmctrl -r `wmctrl -l | grep [t]hunderbird | cut -f1` -t 1
```

## [Compiz Place plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place)

You can enable and configure this if you install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager].

Allows you to set fixed positions for windows with specific titles.

---

FYI, previously I used `wmctrl` in Gnome. Some of its features don't work for me in 11.04 w/ Unity, but should be good in 9.04. Not sure about KDE though.

Answer (score 2):

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

And create a script (in this example thunderbird on the second workspace (`-t 1`)):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
thunderbird 
wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1
```

To know your application name on wmctrl you can view it by taping on your terminal :

```
wmctrl -l
```

And replace it with the correct name in the script.

Be carrefull with the capital letter ("Thunderbird" not "thunderbird") !!

Other example with firefox on the 3d workspace (`-t 2`):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
firefox 
wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Firefox` -t 2
```

Work on Debain 10 with Cinnamon. But should work for all

Answer (score -1):

I am now using [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/): I can easily move windows to any screen/desktop using keyboard.